# Polling in Asynquence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I'd like to implement polling in asynquense. I have been able to do the polling via recursion, but I'm not getting control back to the main sequence once the polling is complete.

The example code:

```
function countdown(count){
    return ASQ().then(function(done){
        //  This is where the call http call would be made...
        console.log("Countdown: " +count);
        if (count){
            return countdown(count-1);
        }
        done();
    })
}
function viewSvg(visId) {
    console.log("viewSvg");

    ASQ()
        .then(function(done) {
            console.log("Stage 1");
            done();
        })
        .val(4)
        .seq(countdown)
        .then(function(done){
            console.log("Stage 5");
            done();
        });
```

Produces the results:

```
Stage 1
Countdown: 4
Countdown: 3
Countdown: 2
Countdown: 1
Countdown: 0
```

Note that Stage 5 is not printed:

I have created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hamish/dw63uvmh/5/)

I'm sure I'm just doing something simple wrong, can anyone give me some assistance?

When I was learning asnquence, I noticed a similar behaviour (ie, control did not return to the main sequence) when I was calling .then(my_function) where my_function also created a sequence. I worked out that calling .seq() was the right thing to do, but it doesn't appear to work with recursion...

Comment: I don't know asynquence well, but my bet would be on `return`ing `countdown(count-1)` from that `.then()` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you must not return a sequence from that `then` callback. Use `seq` instead:

```
function countdown(count){
    return ASQ().seq(function(){
        addRow("log2", "Countdown: " +count);
        if (count) {
            return countdown(count-1);
        } else {
            return ASQ();
        }
    });
}
```

([updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dw63uvmh/2/))

Comment: Thanks so much - And so quickly!